# Separate string : 2 labels

Tags: ios, nsstring, uilabel

I have one long string :

```
NSString* string=@"I'm very long, you can't handle me in one small label, you should separate me and use 2 labels";
```

So i have two labels. I want to cut the head of the string to fit first label : 
`[string giveMeSomeTextSuitableForFirstLabel]`   - as example;
result should be: `@"I'm very long"`
and the rest of the string should be: `@", you can't handle me in one small label, you should separate me and use 2 labels";`

I can't use 1 label instead of two, because there is one image on the corner that covers my first line.

Comment: Find the first comma, then cut the string into two substrings. This is a trivial thing, no?

Comment: so, where are you stuck at?

Comment: string can contain  no commas at all @"String can be everything you can imagine abacbabc"

Comment: would it be enough to use one label with multiple lines?

Comment: How can i find the piece of text that suits my first label. I don't have any ideas..

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I used to have 2 labels(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14633050/118091) might be what you're looking for:

`labelOne.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;`

Then [calculate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14633050/118091) the size of the text chunk.