# Limit the height of a UILabel inside a UIScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, autolayout

I have a UILabel inside a `UIScrollView` and the contentSize of the `UIScrollView` is determined by the amount of text in the `UILabel`. I have managed to define a minimum height for the contentView inside the `UIScrollView` by making the height, width and aspect ratio constraints optional.

This is how the hierarchy of the `UIScrollView` looks like -

```
UIScrollView
    contentView
        UILabel
```

In some cases, even when the text is huge and makes the label expand beyond it's frame, I wish to have the frame of the `UILabel` stick to it's square frame with the extra text getting truncated. I am using autolayout so I believe this won't be possible by merely setting the frame of the `UILabel` and it has something to do with changing the priorities of the constraints.

Constraints for the `UILabel` - 
 The `UILabel` has its leading, trailing, top and bottom connected to the contentView.

Constraints for the `UISCrollView`-

**Required**

Trailing, Leading, Top and Bottom to the superview i.e. the `UIScrollView`

**Optional**

Equal height and width to the superview (`UIScrollView`) and aspect ratio = 1:1

**EDIT**

And I need to do it in a way that when I set the `lineBreakMode` of the `UILabel` to `NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail`, the text automatically gets truncated and `textLabel.text` only returns the visible text.

Comment: why dont you use UITextView instead of UILabel?

Comment: @AbdulWaheed I can't because of certain other limitations

Comment: use tableview instead of scrollview .

Comment: I would say that is more of a hack @KKRocks

Comment: Its hard to say, could you list all your constraints? Also, have you tried adding an inequality constraint for the label, such that `label.height <= label.width`?

Comment: I get what you are saying though. Use UITableViewAutomaticDimension when I have to let it expand and use the width of label as it's height when I have to make it square-sized, right?

Comment: try this : http://stackoverflow.com/a/29365674/3901620

Comment: no you need to add only top, bottom, trailing and leading constraints to label . and code of UITableViewAutomaticDimension.

Comment: @Losiowaty Wouldn't that inequality constraint make the label never expand beyond it's square frame? I need it to expand as long as it can but, let's say on the press of a button, I need to shrink it to a square with the extra text getting truncated

Comment: Ah, didn't catch that from the question - if you have an `IBOutlet` for a constraint you can simply disable/enable it whenever necessary, or even swap constraints.

Comment: @Losiowaty I am adding all the constraints to my question. Can you please let me know which all constraints I need to swap?

Comment: Use this answer from Hashem Aboonajmi - http://stackoverflow.com/a/14633050/4533932

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so if I understand everything correctly, you want to have an expandable label that either shows its entire text, or has a square form. This should as easy as enabling/disabling a constraint such that `label.height <= label.width` (or `==`, depending on what you want it to look like if there is less text then would fit a square label). You can create this constraint in interface builder, add an outlet for it and then simply do:
`self.labelSquareConstraint.active = YES/NO;`

As to the question in your edit : there is no easy way to get the visible part of the text from a label, but there are some threads on SO about this, for example :
[Get truncated text from UILabel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6728259/get-truncated-text-from-uilabel)
[UILabel visible part of text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4100421/uilabel-visible-part-of-text)
[Calculate the range of visible text in UILabel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32311256/calculate-the-range-of-visible-text-in-uilabel/32311302)

Comment: I have been using the code from that third link you provided. Unfortunately, it returns too big a substring to fit into the `UILabel`

Comment: I see 2 different approaches to this - 1. Calculate the amount of text that would fit into a square frame and set the text or 2. Have the label stick to its square frame somehow and then still calculate the visible text which renders the second approach useless altogether

Comment: The second answer from the third link did it for me. Even though a little inaccurate for some fonts, it does a good enough job